# Laravel disable column in eleoquent model

Tags: laravel-5

We have an application with a table, what i want is to disable/read-only one column in my Model, in my example fakecolumn.

So not massasign with `$fillable`.

I don't want any actions tobe done on that specific column.

Table:

```
id
name
email
fakecolumn
```

How can i achieve that and is it also possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an empty [Mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator):

```php
public function setFakecolumnAttribute() {}
```

If you do want to set/update it at some point, you can directly modify the value in the `$attributes` property of the model:

```php
public function init()
{
    $this->attributes['facecolumn'] = true;
}
```